# Given a stream of background locations, is there a commonly used algorithm to identify if a user stayed in one place long enough to be a visit?

Tags: android, ios, swift, react-native, expo

I know iOS has a Visits Location Service (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_visits_location_service), but it doesn't seem like there's a suitable React Native / Expo equivalent. There is an ability to get locations in foreground or background, is there an algorithm that's used to evaluate if a user has been in one place for a while?

Comment: Have you tried making one yourself? I would model it as an array of `Location` objects, where each `Location` stores a timestamp, a change in distance latitudinally since the last entry, and a change in distance longitudinally since the last entry. I would set reasonable thresholds for distance and time to qualify for a user staying in one place (say 200 feet and 10 minutes). I would then iterate backwards through my array, comparing relative timestamps and distances traveled against my most recent entry. If an array entry doesn't qualify, all entries prior to and including it are removed.

Comment: If there isn' a react-native plugin to interact with Apple's visits API, it would almost certainly be simpler to create one than trying to reproduce the visits API yourself.  It is much more battery friendly to use Apple's framework and it has complex heuristics that can determine, after the fact, when a visit started.  It also factors in device motion to tell the difference between stopping at a location vs stopping at a red light in a car.  To integrate with the Visits API you pretty much need to implement a single delegate method.